# How to render the icon in Material table Header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

> Hi to all, I need to render icons in the Material table header column. How can I add it?. It is possible to add the icon in the Header column in Material Table.

Sample Code:

```
    function PositioningActionsColumn() {
      return (
        <MaterialTable
          title="Positioning Actions Column Preview"
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
            { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            {
              title: 'Birth Place',
              field: 'birthCity',
              lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
            },
          ]}
          data={[
            { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
            { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
          ]}
          actions={[
            {
              icon: 'save',
              tooltip: 'Save User',
              onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
            },
            rowData => ({
              icon: 'delete',
              tooltip: 'Delete User',
              onClick: (event, rowData) => confirm("You want to delete " + rowData.name),
              disabled: rowData.birthYear < 2000
            })
          ]}
          options={{
            actionsColumnIndex: -1
          }}
        />
      )
    }
```

Output:
[image: OutPut]

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: U mean u want the save button in the birth place column with the functionality of saving?

Comment: Save Button or any other icon needs to be added near any column header.

Comment: did u try overriding the header component of the material-table?

Comment: In the table, the Phone number column is hidden. So, in the phone number, column (Header) near I add the visible icon, Once, the user clicks the icon, a pop-up will be opened. Then, the user enters the password, the password is valid, the user is able to see the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You may use render:

```
columns={[
  {
    field: 'url',
    title: 'Avatar',
    render: rowData => <img src={rowData.url} style={{width: 50, borderRadius: '50%'}}/>
  }
]}
```

Or components:

```
components={{
    Toolbar: props => (
        <MTableCell {...props} >
           // props.rowData
           <Button .../>
        </MTableCell>
    )
}}
```